# Execute javascript after loading template into view AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm new to Angular and trying to figure out how to run JavaScript which is only specific to one template.

If I include the script in the main page, it doesn't work bevause the specifric DOM relevant to the template has not been loaded yet.

I've tried Event Delegation but that's not working.

Is there a way to include the script inside the controller so it runs after the template called has loaded?

This is my code:

```
        .when("/user-form", {
        templateUrl: "templates/form.html", 
        controller: "FormControl"})


        app.controller('FormControl', function($scope) {

        });
```

Comment: what does the script do? Can you show a sample? You normally would use a directive for it but helps to have better idea of what it's for

Comment: You should put the JS code inside a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: if the code is DOM related, you should put it in a directive like @AlonEitan said.

Comment: @charlietfl The javscript is to make IE8 display css checkboxes correctly, taken from here http://www.csscheckbox.com/article/6/how-to-use-css-checkbox-on-internet-explorer-8-and-older/

It's too long to paste i'm afraid

Comment: IE8 is dead. Angular doesn't support it and neither [is Microsoft supporting it any more](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support)

Comment: @sdfcare  How do I put it in a directive?  I've already searched for help on this, but I can't make sense of it.  If you have any easy links to examples i'd really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Usually you need to declare directives (those are your independent (or semi-independent) template-blocks which have own encapsulated logic.

You need to register directives, and usually it is better done using DDO - Directive Definition Object (check snippet below)

1st there is link function, which is part of DDO (directive definition object) in angular, and happens once all DOM already been rendered.

`app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      templateUrl: 'templates/myTemplate.html',
      controller: ControllerFunction,
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      // your link function code
      } 
    };
   });`

There are plenty of guides about link function and it's place in the rendering cycle.

there are also ways to deal with async data binding within controller, and usually it creates better and more maintenable practice, as link function structure normally intends to be more dom-manipulative and jquery-like.

As i understand from your question you just need to read more material on angular directives, their templates, data binding, their DDO and DDO structure and it's standard properties and methods.

Good Luck!